# Domain setup on DreamHost to Heroku

Tags: heroku, dreamhost, nameservers

I am moving my rails applications form DreamHost to Heroku.
Name servers are still on DreamHost.

Here's how I set up:

```
www.mydomain.com: CNAME to mydomain.herokuapp.com
mydomain.com redirected to www.mydomain.com
```

This sort of works.

But mydomain.com/admin doesn't work.
I must go to www.mydomain.com/admin.

How can I make mydomain.com/admin work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mydomain.com` is forwarded to `www.mydomain.com` correct? Then `mydomain.com/admin` wont work, everything `mydomain.com` is forwarded.

If you want this behavior then you need to remove your forwarding at the DNS and do this kind of redirection (or not) at the application level.